# WebRTCStats - GoogRTT and PacketsLost is null sometimes

Tags: webrtc

Just wondering why this might be the case.

Looking over an entire media session between two WebRTC peers, it seems that some reports from the 'send' audio channel have `null` values for `googRtt` and `packetsLost`. Is there a reason for this?

Example:

```
"sendAudioChannel": {
            "googCodecName": "opus",
            "googRtt": null,
            "bytesSent": 22636,
            "packetsSent": 190,
            "packetsLost": null,
            "audioInputLevel": 0,
            "googJitterReceived": null,
            "googResidualEchoLikelihood": 0,
            "googEchoCancellationReturnLoss": -100,
            "googVoiceCaptureToPacketDelayMs": 0,
            "googEchoCancellationReturnLossEnhancement": -100
          }
```

This event is from half way through the call.

Comment: if that behaviour persists in the not deprecated stats please file an issue at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/list

Comment: Ah, so it isn't normal behaviour. Okay, I'll do so.

Comment: the legacy stats have a lot of quirks. Out of curiosity, is googRtt null all the time?

Comment: Only on some events. It's more often null at the start though.